# How to restrict mouse wheel zoom levels to those specified in View.resolutions?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I would like to restrict mouse wheel zoom levels to those specified in View.resolutions.

What can I do to achieve it?

Comment: Use `constrainResolution: true` in the view options

Answer (score 1):

> Use constrainResolution: true in the view options

(c) Mike

**EDIT**:
If you would like to use *constrainResolution* only for mouse wheel zoom, then you should override function *handleWheelZoom_* in prototype *MouseWheelZoom* before create map:

```
import { clamp } from 'ol/math.js';
import { zoomByDelta } from 'ol/interaction/Interaction';
import { MouseWheelZoom } from "ol/interaction";

const mouseWheelZoomContrainResolution = true;

MouseWheelZoom.prototype.handleWheelZoom_ = function (map) {
    var view = map.getView();
    if (view.getAnimating()) {
        view.cancelAnimations();
    }
    var delta = -clamp(this.totalDelta_, -this.maxDelta_ * this.deltaPerZoom_, this.maxDelta_ * this.deltaPerZoom_) / this.deltaPerZoom_;
    if (view.getConstrainResolution() || mouseWheelZoomContrainResolution) {
        // view has a zoom constraint, zoom by 1
        delta = delta ? delta > 0 ? 1 : -1 : 0;
    }
    zoomByDelta(view, delta, this.lastAnchor_, this.duration_);
    this.mode_ = undefined;
    this.totalDelta_ = 0;
    this.lastAnchor_ = null;
    this.startTime_ = undefined;
    this.timeoutId_ = undefined;
};
```

**EDIT2**:

> The view has a setConstrainResolution method so you can turn the
>   constraint on and off. You can turn it off before setting the zoom
>   manually and turn it back on if any further change is made to the
>   resolution

(c) Mike

See comments below

Comment: The view has a setConstrainResolution method so you can turn the constraint on and off.  You can turn it off before setting the zoom manually and turn it back on if any further change is made to the resolution  https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-6fxtj

Comment: @Mike good hit, but it is not working for me, when I again set constrainResolution to true, then the resolution is moved to predefined https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-ni8lp

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to reset until there is a mousewheel action which triggers a `change:resolution` event

Comment: @Mike still not working, when two times in a row set resolution without using mouse wheel https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-njd8f

Comment: Create a function if you want to do it repeatedly https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-ken9r

Comment: @Mike nice, now with unByKey everything works properly. Thank you for your help!